# Does streaming a video or downloading a video take up more of your internet data?

Tags: video, internet, download, streaming, file-download

I figured that in theory, you are just transferring the same data at the end of the day. I have a feeling that it would take up the same amount of data.

Am I wrong? Is there some other factor that affects the amount of internet data it takes up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is; it depends.

You are correct that downloading and streaming are both transferring the same file to your PC so, all other things being equal, the amount of data used would be the same.

However, many streaming services (including YouTube and Netflix) will automatically downscale (i.e. reduce the bitrate) a video adaptively to suit the available download speed of the viewer. If a 2 hour video is in 1080p but would take 4 hours to download that's not an issue, but obviously you can't stream it like that so the video is downgraded to a quality that it can stream it seamlessly (e.g. 720p). In this case, less data would be transferred by streaming it.